# What does 'downward pressure on sample size' mean?

Tags: sample-size, sample, psychometrics, definition, psychology

In [this article](https://www.eflglobal.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/09/EFL-Technical-Note-July-2012_s.pdf), there is this phrase 'downward pressure on sample size'.

This is the paragraph:

> no     matter  the     approach to     collecting  this    new     data,   when attempting     to  create  scorecards  that    leverage    psychometric    data (or    any     other   type    of  data    which   must    be  newly   collected  from    applicants  rather  than    pulled  from    old application forms   or  secondary   sources) there  will    be  downward    pressure    on  sample  size.

What does that mean? Such a phrase exists in other articles: [1](http://www.bmj.com/content/345/bmj.e5278/rr/609971) [2](http://www.ctspedia.org/do/view/CTSpedia/EthicsSampleSize)

Comment: Probably the just mean that it will be costly to collect data ..., so budgetary constraints is that "downward pressure"?

Comment: @kjetilbhalvorsen Downward pressure on = more costly to increase?

Comment: @BenedictM.J.G. oh alright thanks. Finished the project for that class later that month but good to know :P Post as answer?

Comment: @BCLC Right, I got carried away. I have deleted my comment and expanded it into an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It simply means that there is pressure to keep the sample size as small as possible and most likely smaller than could be desired by someone whose sole interest was in maximizing information quality - be if for inference, prediction, or merely for descriptive purposes.

Many reasons can be imagined: social convention, monetary costs, ethical concerns (e.g., if subjects might suffer), time constraints, or avoiding precedents. It might simply be the case that the expected result is unwelcome and some party with influence over the research process is seeking to compromise the data.

The party under pressure to minimize sample size need not be a researcher, either; it could be an organizational unit, a social group, a company. Indeed, researchers might themselves apply pressure, e.g., pressuring a colleague to keep sample sizes in line with their field's conventions, possibly to avoid setting a costly precedent (costly in terms of money or lost opportunity to publish spurious results).